# How make tkinter grid_forget resize LabelFrame?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a frame that holds buttons and it's packed in a LabelFrame with grid geometry manager.
When I remove this frame with grid_forget, the LabelFrame still has the same size.
With other words
it doesn't shrink.

Here is the code, when you press the button all the buttons are removed
but the size remains.
I expected that the grid geometry manager deals automatically with resizing when widgets are removed.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Collapsible():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master        
        self.dynamic_widgets()
        self.fill_lb()
        
    def dynamic_widgets(self):
        """create widgets"""
        #frame that holds labelwidgets
        self.fr_collapse = tk.Frame(self.master, bg="orange")
        
        #title for label frame----------------------------------------------------------------
        self.bt_title = tk.Button(self.fr_collapse, text="o", 
                                  highlightthickness = 0, bd = 0, 
                                  relief="flat", bg="orange", fg="red")
        self.bt_title.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.label_title = tk.Label(self.fr_collapse, text="Name", bg="orange")
        self.label_title.grid(row=0, column=1)
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        
        self.label_frame = tk.LabelFrame(self.master,  
                                              bg="orange", labelwidget=self.fr_collapse)
        self.label_frame.grid(sticky="wesn", ipady=(10))  
        
        #frame for buttons
        self.frame_forget = tk.Frame(self.label_frame, bg="orange")
        self.frame_forget.grid()
        
        #set command
        self.bt_title.configure(command=lambda x=self.frame_forget, y=self.bt_title: self.hide(x, y))
        
    def fill_lb(self):
        "fill label frame with dumb buttons"""
        b = tk.Button(self.frame_forget, text="Example button 1", bg="orange", relief="flat")
        b.grid()
        b2 = tk.Button(self.frame_forget, text="Example button 2", bg="orange", relief="flat")
        b2.grid()
        
    def hide(self, frame, button):        
        """switch value: hide frame based on text configuration"""
        bt_text  = button.configure("text")
        if bt_text[-1] == "o":
            frame.grid_remove()
            button.configure(text="-")
        else:
            frame.grid()
            button.configure(text="o")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    col = Collapsible(root)
    root.configure(bg="orange")
    root.mainloop()
```

- What I tried so far:

  - I thought that maybe I need to grid frame that holds buttons after deleting them. Does'n work because this will
    grid my hidden buttons again which is logically.
  - I thought that maybe I need to grid the LableFrame again. No changes in size either
  - I thought that maybe I should put a dumb frame like a placeholder with minimal width and height values.
    and grid it as child in my frame_forget frame with the hope that it will shrink. But still nothing.

None of those thoughts brought me a solution and the question remains

When I run my script it looks like this:
[image]

Then when I press flat button in the left corner 'o', I get this:
[image]

I wish it would collapse like this one:
[image]

Comment: How does one reproduce the problem running the code in your question?

Comment: When the *last item* of a container is removed, the container will not adjust its size.  You can add a `Frame` of height 1 before `self.frame_forget`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in line 46,   `width` and `height`  in `self.label_frame` parameter.
code:

```
if bt_text[-1] == "o":
    frame.grid_remove()
    self.label_frame.configure(height=20, width=150) #  <--- line 46
```

Screenshot:

[image]